# How to use jQuery with vaadin 6

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, vaadin

I have created a very simple VAADIN project which has two files in src. a servlet class (extends ApplicationServlet) where i put a link to jQuery file in body tag. Here is the code:

```
public class servlet extends ApplicationServlet{
@Override
protected void writeAjaxPageHtmlHeader(final BufferedWriter page, String title, String themeUri,
        final HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
    //Don't forget to call super or nothing will work
    page.write("<script type=\"text/javascript\"> src=\"/jqueryhtml/VAADIN/themes/simple/jquery-1.4.4.min.js\" </script>");
    page.write("<script type=\"text/javascript\"> src=\"/jqueryhtml/VAADIN/themes/simple/testingjs.js\" </script>");
    super.writeAjaxPageHtmlHeader(page, title, themeUri, request);

}
}
```

and replace the default servlet with this in web.xml file. 
Other than this, i have a html file which has only this line.

```
 <div id="test">Click Me for alert Box</div>
```

This file resides in layout/themes folder.

I have an application file that loads the theme. here is the code:

```
 public class JqueryhtmlApplication extends Application {
@Override
public void init() {
    Window mainWindow = new Window("Fullscreensignature Application");

    Panel panel = new Panel("Login");
    panel.setSizeUndefined();

    // Create custom layout from "layoutname.html" template.
    CustomLayout custom = new CustomLayout("simple");

    // Use it as the layout of the Panel.
    panel.setContent(custom);

    mainWindow.addComponent(panel);

    mainWindow.setTheme("simple");

    setMainWindow(mainWindow);
}

}
```

here is my jQuery file.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('#test').click(function(){
 alert("You can see a alert box");
 });
 });
```

Output says:

Click me for alert box (as i wrote in a div).

Now the problem is, it loads the HTML,css and jQuery file correctly (i can see in my browser inspect element). but the jQuery does not works when i click on it. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated. Thank you,

Regards,

Hassan

Comment: Have you looked at integrating a custom javascript component? https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/gwt.javascript.html#gwt.javascript.server-side

Comment: Oh sorry, i forgot to answer this post myself. The problem has been solved now. The scripts you include in servlet are just to declares functions. and you have to call it from main application class like 'mainWindow.executeJavascript("MyloadFunction()");'